# django push notification to android using django-push-notifications library

Tags: android, python, django, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android application with a backend web application developed in django.

I am using [django-push-notification](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-push-notifications/1.0.1) library to enable push notification in my django backend application.

In the android application I send the registration id to the backend django application and it is stored in the DB successfully.

When I try to send the test message from the admin area, I got a confirmation that all messages are sent but I did not receive any message on my android application.

I suspected the android application but I wrote some code to test the application receiver and it worked fine, so I think the problem is in the django application.

Is there any method to make sure that the messages sent from the django app is received by the google cloud messaging service ?

Answer (score 1):

I worked with GCM and django-push-notification long time ago. Although I do no clearly remember, but you can try something like:

- Check the response from GCM after django send message.
- Make sure that your android app use the right key for getting the message body( I remember that django-push-notification use `msg` key)

Comment: thnx Toan. For the second point, I did not receive any thing on the android app. I run the application in debug mode and put a break point on the first method in the receiver but nothing happen. For the first point, How could I check the GCM response? sorry I am a newbie in python/Djagno.

Comment: The `send_message()` method returns GCM response. So you can assign `response = gcmdevice.send_message(...)` then `print response`.